# M2 - Markup changing when a product has been added to wishlist

Tags: magento2, theme, product-view, phtml, wishlist

For some reason adding a product to my wishlist changes the markup of my add to wishlist button.

Screenshots:

**Before adding to wishlist**

```
<a href="#" class="action towishlist wishlist-button" data-post="data-post-here" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span>+ Add to wishlist</span></a>
```

[image]

**After adding to wishlist**

```
<div class="split button wishlist">
        <button type="button" data-post="data-post-here" data-action="add-to-wishlist" class="label action split">
            <span>+ Add to wishlist</span>
        </button>
        <button class="action toggle change" title="Add to:" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span>Add to:</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="items" data-target="dropdown" aria-hidden="true">

                <li class="item">

                        <span data-post="data-post-here" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="Wish List">
                            Wish List
                        </span>

                </li>

                <li class="item">

                        <span class="action new" data-post-new-wishlist="data-post-here" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="Create New Wish List">
                            <span>Create New Wish List</span>
                        </span>

                </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

[image]

The template used to render the wishlist and add to bag button is `/var/www/vhosts/client-name/production/htdocs/app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`.

Yet once a product has been added to my wishlist it appears to use this template - `vendor/magento/module-multiple-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/behaviour.phtml`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the reason for this is to render a dropdown with additional options such as add a product to a new wishlist.

As I don't require this functionality I've removed the behaviour.phtml template via my XML. The button now remains consistent, the only downside is the user now needs to go to the wishlist page to add a new wishlist.

`app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Remove wishlist behaviour -->
        <referenceBlock name="wishlist_behaviour" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Hopefully this will help someone out who runs into the same confusion.